# Filling an empty list using .extend from a user input

Tags: python, list, extend

I would like to try and use the input function to allow the user to enter multiple values into a list.  Can this be done using the extend method? Here is a simple example

```
sports = []
x = input("Enter your 3 favourite sports:")
sports.extend(x)
print(sports)

#However, this results in each letter being entered individually:

Enter your 3 favourite sports: football rugby polo
['f', 'o', 'o', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l', ' ', 'r', 'u', 'g', 'b', 'y', ' ', 'p', 'o', 'l', 'o']
```

Is there a way to use .extend() with multiple values from an input?  I've managed to use a for loop and .append() to add 1 item at a time to a list using an input.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using ```split(" ")```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` if you're sure the sports are separated by a space character:

```
sports = []
x = input("Enter your 3 favourite sports: ")
sports.extend(x.split())
print(sports)
```

Input:

```
Enter your 3 favourite sports: footbal rugby polo
```

Output:

```
['footbal', 'rugby', 'polo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the input that you get from the user by a space. Then, extend the list using these values. Here is the full code to do it:

```
sports = []
x = input("Enter your 3 favourite sports:").split(' ')
sports.extend(x)
print(sports)
```

Output:

```
Enter your 3 favourite sports:>? football rugby polo
['football', 'rugby', 'polo']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input`  function you get a string in return. You then need to split it into a list of substrings, each one representing a sport:

```
sports = []
x = input("Enter your 3 favourite sports:")
new_sports = x.split() # = x.split(" ") i.e. split using space 
sports.extend(x)
print(sports)
```

If you want to make sure that the substrings are exactly 3, you could use

```
assert len(new_sports) == 3
```

which throws an `AssertionError` when the statement is `False`, or you could just use something like

```
if len(new_sports) != 3:
    print("You did not insert exactly 3 sports!")
else:
    sports.extend(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split with exact delimiter `x.split("delim")`

```
sports = []
x = input("Enter your 3 favourite sports: ")
sports.extend(x.split(",")) # Here is comma
print(sports)
```